# Tracing Variables in AS3 is not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

```
var a:Number;
var b:Number;

a + b = 17;

trace ("A: "a"       B: "b);
```

Why does this not work? Is there somthing about tracing multiple pieces of information in  the same trace statement in AS3?

Comment: It confuses me that `a + b = 17` does work...

Comment: I'd suggest modifying the name of your question to something more descriptive such as "Tracing Variables in AS3 is not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. The one the other answers apply to is the trace problem. The argument of a trace() call is any number of strings, separated by comma's. However, it is very common to just supply one and concatenate the string parts with the `+` sign.

```
trace("A: "+a+", B: "+b);
```

The real problem in your code however is `a + b = 17`, both in writing and in thinking. You cannot calculate the numeric outcome of an equation if you have more than one undetermined variable in there. A + B = C is only solvable in code if you know two of the three variables. If you want to write something moderately useful, try

```
var a:Number = 5;
var b:Number;

b = 12 - a;

trace("A: "+a+", B: "+b);
```

Apart from the math thinking, in code you're not writing math equations, you're writing assignment expressions. Whatever expression is to the right of the `=` sign, will get assigned to the variable to the left of the `=` sign. It will never work to assign one expression to two variables with an operator (`+, *, -, /, %`, etc) and hope that the math will magically resolve itself. `a + b = something` will never work, `something = a + b` might. In addition, trying to assign something to a constant and hoping it will resolve itself, like `12 = a + b`, will also not work.

Cheers.

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that it always thought of different solution, each time you ran it?

Comment: You're looking for Math.random(). It creates a random number between 0.0 and 1.0. If you multiply that with your maximum, like Math.random() * 10 if you want a number between 0 and 10, you're on your way.

Comment: Thanks again. This is confusing but the puzzle pieces are starting to fall into place if i may say so without slipping into cliché.

Comment: Also, how would you trace the result?

Comment: What do you mean by "trace the result"? you can throw anything in the trace() method.

Comment: trace(Math.random()*13). From your question and your comments, I'm assuming that you're new to programming in general, not merely actionscript. You will advance a lot faster, if you start out with a book. This is a classic that will get you up to speed in no time: http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946

Comment: Thank you very much, I will get that. I had a bit of experience a while back but, I forgot just about everything.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the plus (+) symbol to concatenate strings together.

```
trace ("A: " + a + "B: " + b);
```

Answer (score 2):

In ActionScript 3, the trace method can take many parameters. But they must be comma seperated like any method call. So you could use:

```
trace ("A:", a, "B:", b);
```